# Сервер mysql ругается на ' - одинарную кавычку

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c

Всем привет. Имеется приложение на [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c). Приложение периодически отправляет текст на сервер. Но если в передаваемом тексте имеется `'` -  одинарная кавычка, то от сервера приходит следующее сообщение:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dded. Dad add\"'','','')' at line 1";

Передается текст в `POST` запросе. Как решить эту проблему??

...

Дело в том что на сервер отправляется скажем так текст сообщения, который набирает пользователь приложения. Текст с остальными  атрибутами упаковывается в NSDictionary и далее отправляется в виде POST параметров на сервер. Текст набранный пользователем может иметь например такой вид: I'll be back. И при отправке этого текста возникает ошибка.

Comment: Очевидно, что их стоит экранировать...и для начала Выберите какими именно кавычками в запросе Вы сами будете пользоваться. А то двойные у Вас экранированы, при этом строку Вы в одинарные кладёте. Выберите что-то одно.

Comment: В objective-c нет подготовленных выражений при составлении запросов к БД? mysql_stmt_init(), mysql_stmt_prepare(),  mysql_stmt_bind_param(), mysql_stmt_execute(), mysql_stmt_close() ;)

Comment: Дело в том что на сервер отправляется скажем так текст сообщения, который набирает пользователь приложения. Текст с остальными атрибутами упаковывается в NSDictionary и далее отправляется в виде POST параметров на сервер. Текст набранный пользователем может иметь например такой вид: I'll be back. И при отправке этого текста возникает ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самым простым вариантом решения будет замена одинарной кавычки на что-то типа - **`** символ обратного апострофа. А правильным вариантом решения проблемы будет экранирование символов, которые могут исполнятся как код, читайте про [sql-injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Ваша ошибка скорее всего связана с тем, что Вы пишете в базу непосредственно пользовательский текст, а так делать не надо, например:

```
resp = get()  # типа получили данные от пользователя
db.session('select * from table where id = {0}'.format(resp))  # обратились к базе
```

так вот, если `resp = '1'` все норм, но пользователь может отправить что-то другое, и теперь у вас `resp = '1; DELETE FROM table;'`

Comment: Дело в том что на сервер отправляется скажем так текст сообщения, который набирает пользователь приложения. Текст с остальными атрибутами упаковывается в NSDictionary и далее отправляется в виде POST параметров на сервер. Текст набранный пользователем может иметь например такой вид: I'll be back. И при отправке этого текста возникает ошибка.

Comment: Я ж кинул ссыль, что почитать, поздравляю - у Вас на сервере беда, дырка, чтерез которую можно стереть базу, например, меняйте серверную часть, добавляйте экранирование, чтобы пользовательский текст не выполнялся к sql команда

Answer (score 0):

В приложении перед отправкой строки на сервер для замены конкретного символа '

```
NSString *newString = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurancesOfString:@"'" withString:@"%27"];
```

или для всех неподходящих символов

```
NSString *newString = [originalString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```